# The annihilator $\mathrm{Ann}_R(m)\subseteq R$ is a maximal left ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with $1_R$, $M$ a *simple* left $R$-module and $m\in M$ is a non-zero element.

***We would like to prove that the annihilator $\mathrm{Ann}_R(m)\subseteq R$ is a maximal left ideal of $R$.***

It may be something obvious but unfortunately I can't see it.

To prove that it is a left ideal is easy. Now I stuck at the maximality. The first thought is to assume that 
$$\mathrm{Ann}_R(m) \subsetneqq J \subseteq R.$$
So, it suffices to show that in this case $J=R$.

We know that since $$\mathrm{Ann}_R(m) \subsetneqq J\implies\exists j\in J \setminus \mathrm{Ann}_R(m) \implies jm\neq 0_M \implies jm=n,$$ for some $n\neq 0_M$.

So if we take an element $x\in R$ we should show that $x\in J$. But how?

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M$ is simple, so it's cyclic, hence $M=Rm$. But $n=jm\neq 0$ is also in $M$, so $Rn=M$. As $m\in M$, there is an $r\in R$ such that $m=rn=rjm$, meaning $rj-1\in\text{Ann}_{R}(m)$. Yet since $\text{Ann}_{R}(m)\subset J$, we have $rj-1\in J$, but $rj\in J$ so we also have $1\in J$.